# List of Abbreviations not showing

Tags: table-of-contents, compiling

I had a list of abbreviations, which worked fine, but now it's not showing any more. And I have no idea what I could've changed. It is shown in the table of content, but also on the wrong position.
My preamble:

```
\newcommand{\Abkuerzung}{
    \printnomenclature
    \newpage
}
```

The place where it should be displayed:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\noname}
\Abkuerzung
```

My abbreviations
    \abbrev{dex}{Dalvik Executable}
    :
How I build it:

```
pdflatex file.tex
makeindex file.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o file.nls
pdflatex file.tex
pdflatex file.tex
```

my output of makeindex:

```
Scanning style file /usr/share/texmf-dist/makeindex/nomencl/nomencl.ist....done(10 attributes redefined, 3 ignored).
Scanning input file file.nlo...done (0 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Nothing written in file.nls
Transctipt written in file.ilg
```

I see that there is nothing written into the nls file and nothing happens and so, but what can I do?

**EDIT**

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}                                           

\usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{a4}
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
%That Headings have Kapitälchen:
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{xcolor}

%%%%%%%%%BIBLIOGRAPHY + PICTURES IN TABLE OF CONTENTS
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{breakcites}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%ABKÜRZUNGEN
\usepackage{nomencl}
\let\abbrev\nomenclature
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Abbreviations}
\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{.25\hsize}
\renewcommand{\nomlabel}[1]{#1 \dotfill}
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parsep}
\makenomenclature 
\newcommand{\Abkuerzung}{
\printnomenclature
\newpage
}



\begin{document}

\include{cover}
\include{title}
\include{abstract}
\include{affidavit}

\selectlanguage{english}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{Listings}
\lstlistoflistings
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Listings}
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\nomname}
\Abkuerzung


%%% Chapters
\include{Chapters/introduction}
\include{Chapters/overview}
\include{Chapters/migration}
\include{Chapters/analysis}
\include{Chapters/conclusion}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%BIBLIOGRAPHY%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\nocite{*}
\bibliography{bibliography}{}
%\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%makeindex thesis.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o thesis.nls
\abbrev{dex}{Dalvik Executable}
\abbrev{XML}{Extensible Markup Language}
\abbrev{VM}{Virtual Machine}
\abbrev{JIT}{Just In Time}
\abbrev{DVM}{Dalvik Virtual Machine}
\abbrev{JVM}{Java Virtual Machine}                                         

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Did you remove a `\makenomenclature` line somewhere? And `\noname` should probably be `\nomname`. But yes, an MWE would be helpful.

Comment: @egreg i edited my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, are you making your definitions inline with the text? Since the nomenclature is a specialized index, it's really meant to be used as you're introducing new terms, and not as a big list of items at the end of the document.

That having been said, as long as there's body text in the document, it looks like your code works. Not having any of your included content, the following works fine:

```
\documentclass{report}                                           

\usepackage{nomencl}
\let\abbrev\nomenclature
\makenomenclature 
\newcommand{\Abkuerzung}{
\printnomenclature
\newpage
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\nomname}
\Abkuerzung

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%makeindex thesis.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o thesis.nls
Uncomment this text, so the abbrev command will have something to reference. Otherwise, nothing works.
\abbrev{dex}{Dalvik Executable}
\abbrev{XML}{Extensible Markup Language}
\abbrev{VM}{Virtual Machine}
\abbrev{JIT}{Just In Time}
\abbrev{DVM}{Dalvik Virtual Machine}
\abbrev{JVM}{Java Virtual Machine}     
\end{document}
```

But it didn't work at all until I had actual text in the body of the document. I'll edit or remove this answer depending on what else you find out.

Comment: I added some text above the first \abbrev and built it new, than removed the text again and now it works. Thank you.

Comment: That's not exactly "working", since that last build likely wiped out your `.nlo` file. As long as you never run `makeindex` again, converting the now-empty `.nlo` into a newly-empty `.nls` used by `\printnomenclature`, I guess it'll be ok.